# Building object during chaining of observables

Tags: rxjs, observable

Suppose I have a chain of observables which emit some value that I'd like to use in order to build an object at the end. For example:

```
this.myService.myMethod()
    .map(items => items.map(items => item.id))
    // Save id somehow

    .map(id => this.myService.anotherMethod(id)
    // Save another property here

    .filter(data => data.length > 0)
    // At this point, I'd like to have the above 2 variables as well as
    // access to another property based on what is returned from the previous
    // stream

    this.myObject = this.myObject.concat({
        var1,
        var2,
        var3
    })
)
```

I'm wondering if I could use `combineLatest`, or `merge` or `withLatestFrom` to save these variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [flatMap](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/selectmany.md) (or [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) if you are only interested in first emitted value from the outer observable) which will take each emitted item from the outer observable and use that to create an inner observable which calls your second service method. The first and second emitted values can be combined with a `selector` function which is the second parameter of `flatMap` (and `switchMap`). Like this:

```
   this.myService.myMethod()
       .flatMap(item => this.myService.anotherMethod(item.id), (first, second) => ({ ...first, ...second })
```